# MSCRM 2013 - On Premise - Import Organization error

Tags: sql, tls1.2, dynamics-crm-2013, tls1.0

CRM 2013 On Premise

SQL Server 2012

Update on servers:
TLS 1.0 and 1.1 were disabled. TLS 1.2 is enabled now.

One of the Organizations was deleted and we are trying to re import the same, but it is failing

Error at the last stage while in verification for "Microsoft SQL Server"

Error: "Could not connect to the following SQL Server. Verify that the server is up and running and that you have SQL Server administrative credentials. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (**SECCreateCredentials()**).]SSL Security error."

Temporarily enabled TLS 1.0 for the import but then error updated to:

"Could not connect to the following SQL Server. Verify that the server is up and running and that you have SQL Server administrative credentials. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (**SECDoClientHandshake()**).]SSL Security error."

Account used to do the import has full access of the SQL DB Server.

Help required to identify the cause and do the import of organization successfully.

Comment: On Premises version, I assume? What procedure did you follow deleting the organization?

Comment: Directly from the deployment manager. Disabling and deleting. 
We did this deletion and re importing many times before but after TLS upgrade importing is not working.

Comment: This was resolved by temporarily enabling TLS 1.0 on both CRM App and DB server and restarting them. Import was completed successfully post this task. TLS 1.0 was disabled again.